# Memory leaks in classes of linked nodes

Tags: python, memory-leaks

I'm trying to reimplement (once more... i know...) a simple network in python made of node classes that reference other node classes (their children), and I was wondering what would happen if I create a recursive network (node1 -> node2 -> node3 -> node1) and accidentally lose all references to any of the nodes.

Imagine I have the following code

```
class node():
    def __init__(self):
        self.children = []

    def append(self, child):
        self.children.append(child)

node1 = node()
node2 = node()

node1.append(node2)
node2.append(node1) # now the network is recursive

node1 = 0
# node1 is still referenced in node2.children so will not be deleted
node2 = 0

# now both node1 and node2 are not directly referenced by any variable
# but they are referenced by the two children instances
```

after the last line of code, all references to node1 and node2 are lost, but the memory originally allocated to the nodes sill contain a reference to themselves.

Would node1 and node2 still be destroyed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the objects will be garbage collected. The garbage collector will detect the circular reference and break it so that normal reference counting cleanup can take place. See the [`gc` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/gc.html).

You *would* have a problem if your `node` class implemented a `__del__` method and you are using a Python version < 3.4. In 3.4 now can [break circular references involving instances with `__del__` methods](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.4.html#pep-442-safe-object-finalization) in most cases.

From the [`object.__del__` documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__del__):

> **Note**: `del x` doesn’t directly call `x.__del__()` — the former decrements the reference count for `x` by one, and the latter is only called when `x`‘s reference count reaches zero. Some common situations that may prevent the reference count of an object from going to zero include: circular references between objects (e.g., a doubly-linked list or a tree data structure with parent and child pointers); a reference to the object on the stack frame of a function that caught an exception (the traceback stored in `sys.exc_traceback` keeps the stack frame alive); or a reference to the object on the stack frame that raised an unhandled exception in interactive mode (the traceback stored in `sys.last_traceback` keeps the stack frame alive). The first situation can only be remedied by explicitly breaking the cycles; the latter two situations can be resolved by storing `None` in `sys.exc_traceback` or `sys.last_traceback`. Circular references which are garbage are detected when the option cycle detector is enabled (it’s on by default), but can only be cleaned up if there are no Python-level `__del__()` methods involved. Refer to the documentation for the `gc` module for more information about how `__del__()` methods are handled by the cycle detector, particularly the description of the garbage value.